# Pydev error: Unable to find module to reload

Tags: python, parameters, command-line-arguments, pydev

I wrote a module in python (using `pydev`). Most of my code is written in the `'main'`. In the code, I read from a file. I wrote:

```
inputFile = 'training_data.txt'
```

Later, I tried getting the name of the inputFile as a parameter:

```
inputFile = str(sys.argv[0])
```

When I changed to that, I started getting the following error lots of times:

```
pydev debugger: Unable to find module to reload: "boolean_conj_predictor".
```

**`boolean_conj_predictor` is the name of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str(sys.argv[0])` will be the name of the file you are running. Instead, try to access the next element, i.e., do `inputFile = sys.argv[1]`.

You can observe this behaviour with a simple print statement, within your code, if you put a statement `print sys.argv` and then run your file like `python test.py filename.txt`, you will see the output array as `['test.py', 'filename.txt']`